# Gulp task that write all filenames in another file

Tags: gulp

I'm getting started with Gulp and I want to write a task that does the following:

1. Browse a directory and sub directories to find files using the pattern `*.doc.cjsx`
2. Write all the file path found in another file named `components.coffee`

I'm using [`gulp-inject`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject). I know that I eventually will need to write to a proper JS file instead of a coffee file (to avoid track a content-generated file on git)

Here is my task: (coffee)

```
gulp.task 'react-components', ->
    gulp.src('src/apis/front/commons/components.coffee')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(
            inject(
                gulp.src(
                    [
                        "src/apis/front/commons/button/*.doc.cjsx"
                    ],
                    read: false
                ),
                {
                    ignorePath: 'src/apis/front/commons/'
                    addPrefix: 'require ./' # I need to make the path relative at runtime, I haven't tested this yet because it doesn't generate any output, yet.
                    starttag: '# inject:components'
                }
            )
        )
        .pipe(debug({minimal: false}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/apis/front/commons/'))
```

Here is the `components.coffee` file:

```
module.exports = [
    require "./button/button.doc.js" # This should be auto-generated inside the starting tag and closing tag.

    # inject:components
    # endinject
]
```

Here is the output when I run the task:

```
[10:15:24] Using gulpfile ~/service/www/hapi-rho/gulpfile.coffee
[10:15:24] Starting 'react-components'...
[10:15:24] gulp-inject 1 files into components.coffee.
[10:15:24] gulp-debug: 
cwd:   ~/service/www/hapi-rho
base:  ~/service/www/hapi-rho/src/apis/front/commons/
path:  ~/service/www/hapi-rho/src/apis/front/commons/components.coffee

[10:15:24] gulp-debug: 1 item
[10:15:24] Finished 'react-components' after 31 ms
```

It seems to be working fine because gulp says that it injected 1 file into *components.coffee*, if I add another `*.doc.cjsx` file in the folder then it says it injected two files.

But the content of `components.coffee` *isn't changed*, so I'm obviously missing something. Either the `starttag` isn't found, or it's something else.

---

**Solution**:
Here is my solution, based on Sven's answer. The paths have changed since and I'm generating an object instead of an array now, but the principle is the same.

```
gulp.task 'react-components', ->
    gulp.src('src/apis/front/components/components.coffee')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(
        inject(
            gulp.src('src/apis/front/components/**/*.doc.cjsx', read: false),
            ignorePath: 'src/apis/front/components/'
            starttag: '# inject:components'
            endtag: '# endinject'
            transform: (filepath, file, i, length) ->
                filename = filepath.replace(/cjsx$/, 'js')
                suffix = if i + 1 < length then ',' else ''
                '"' + filename + '": require ".' + filename + '"'# + suffix
        )
    )
    .pipe(debug(minimal: false))
    .pipe gulp.dest('src/apis/front/components/')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you forgot to specify your `endtag`.

Secondly, you need to provide a [`transform`](https://github.com/klei/gulp-inject#optionstransform) option. If you don't explicitly provide one the default transform function will be used, which uses the target file type (`coffee` in your case) and the source file type (`cjsx` in your case) to choose a sensible transformation for you.

Unfortunately there is [no default transformation](https://github.com/klei/gulp-inject/blob/master/src/transform/index.js) for the `coffee`/`cjsx` pairing available. That means you have to write one yourself.

Here's what that might look like in your case (regular JavaScript, since I'm not well-versed in CoffeeScript):

```
gulp.task('react-components', function()  {
  return gulp.src('src/apis/front/commons/components.coffee')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(inject(
       gulp.src("src/apis/front/commons/button/*.doc.cjsx", {read:false}),
       {
         ignorePath: 'src/apis/front/commons/',
         starttag: '# inject:components',
         endtag: '# endinject',
         transform: function (filepath, file, i, length) {
           return 'require ".' + filepath.replace(/cjsx$/, "js") +
                  '"' + (i + 1 < length ? ',' : '');
         }
       }
     ))
    .pipe(debug({minimal: false}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/apis/front/commons/'));
});
```

Comment: No worries about JS/Coffee, there are websites that does the trick ;) http://js2.coffee/